# Service with Reference assembly from Symfony3

Tags: logic, symfony

In my SF3 project, I have two services who depends each other and causes circular references issue :

```
page_handler : 
    arguments : ["@sentence_handler"]
sentence_handler :
    arguments : ["@page_handler"]
```

Because, from class PageHandler I use SentenceHandler to add a sentence to a page, and from SentenceHandler I use PageHandler to get all sentences from Page.

I notice 3 options to fix this :

- Move my addSentence() method to SentenceHandler : But I'll modify a page from SentenceHandler, it's not logical.
- Move getAllSentences() method to PageHandler : But I'll get sentences from PageHandler, it's not logical.
- Duplicate getPage() method from PageHandler to SentenceHandler which will become independent : But it's not DRY

What is the best method ? Have you got another ideas ?

Comment: the worst method is to inject the container in both the service and get the related service when they needed. Usually avoid to do [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html#avoiding-your-code-becoming-dependent-on-the-container)

Comment: Can the getPage functionality be moved into it's own service and injected into the other handlers?  That would take care of your DRY concerns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [setter injection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/injection_types.html#setter-injection) on both services:

```
page_handler:
    class: PageHandler
    calls:
        - ["setSentenceHandler", ["@sentence_handler"]]

sentence_handler:
    class: SentenceHandler
    calls:
        - ["setPageHandler", ["@page_handler"]]
```

As long as you don't need/use the services in the contructor (which is problematic anyway), there will be not noticable difference. Meaning you can safely inject the services into other services later.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know the different types of injection!

Comment: Just be careful.  The trick works but these sort of cross dependencies can make your code difficult to maintain.